# Native Array.prototype.sort() and _.sortBy() sorts values differently

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I am trying to sort array of objects based on an integer property. When using lodash's method `_.sortBy()` the order is as expected but when I use the built in method it isn't right.

Check the snippet here: [jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/xecetax/edit?js,console). It's not the most readable example. I am not able to figure what is wrong with the sort method that I have written. The objects which have delay value 0 should maintain their original order in the array but that's not happening with the native sort method. Let me know in comments if I should edit my example for more clarity.

Comment: I don't undestand your example (try posting a better one), but in general, built-in sort is not guaranteed to be stable (that is, equal objects don't necessary retain their original relative positions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your sort method. However, your expectations might not be entirely correct.

`_.sortBy()` uses a stable sorting algorithm. If it encounters elements that are equal to each other (like your 0 delay values) it leaves the elements in the same order it found them.
http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

`Array.prototype.sort()`'s algorithm on the other hand is not guaranteed to be stable.

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: It's worth noting that ECMAScript 2019 guarantees that Array.prototype.sort is stable, per MDN (which also includes a compatibility table for browsers that do/don't support stable sorting): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sort_stability